# Wait for loops on Firestore collections/documents to end before sending output in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to loop through the documents in a collection, elaborate the documents data, loop throught every document in a collection inside the document cited above and elaborate additional data.
This is my structure:

```
jh (collection)
    x (document)
        data (map)
        provinces (collection)
            x-1 (document)
                data (map)
            x-2 (document)
                data (map)
    y (document)
        data (map)
        provinces (collection)
            y-1 (document)
                data (map)
            y-2 (document)
                data (map)
```

This is the snippet used to loop through all the documents and nested collections of the documents:

```js
var worldData = {}; //TODO fill all the info

// get all the documents inside jh collection
db.collection('jh').get()
.then(collSnap => {
    // loop all country documents
    collSnap.forEach(countrySnap => {
        var countryData = countrySnap.data();
        //
        // TODO elaborate country data => worldData
        //
        // get all documents inside provinces of the country document
        db.collection("jh").doc(countrySnap.id).collection("provinces").get()
        .then(provColl => {
            // loop all province documents
            provColl.forEach(provSnap => {
                var provData = provSnap.data();
                // TODO elaborate country data => worldData
            })
        });
    });
})
//
// FIXME wait for every loop and send the informations
console.log(worldData);
```

How do I wait for all loops to end? I need to send the retrieved data, that I will store in `worldData` variable, via HTTP.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please limit yourself to a single question per post (else it might get closed as "needs more focus").

Comment: @DougStevenson done, thanks.

Comment: You will need to collect promises into an array and use `Promise.all()` to create a new promise that resolves after every other promise resolves.  This is a standard JavaScript practice not unique to Firestore.